# JSONObject get data

Tags: android, json

I want to get some json data for my android app from a website that shows it like this:

```
[ {"id":"33333", "title":"My title" },
  {"id":"33344", "title":"My title 2" },
...
]
```

I have seen some tutorials but i dont realy understand how you can get aal the info in { }.
I have something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonObj.length(); i++) {
        String id = jsonObj.getJSONObject("part").getString("id");
     }
```

But it does not work. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify what the significance of your PHP tag is?

Comment: @Chris I removed it, it's clearly not PHP.

Comment: sorry, I added his by accident.

Answer (score 1):

For you specific array there, you need something like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(your_returned_json_string);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    if (!jsonObj.isNull("id")) {
        // do something with id
    }
    if (!jsonObj.isNull("title")) {
        // do something with title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple.

Consider the following is your JSON Array named **jsonArray**

```
[ 
   {"id":"33333", "title":"My title" },
   {"id":"33344", "title":"My title 2" },
   .....
]
```

You have JSON objects inside this array all of which have a similar format. Hence you need to extract them one by one. This is where the for loop comes into play.

```
for(int i=0 ; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //Get each JSONObject

    //Now jsonObject will contain 'i'th jsonObject
    //Extracting data from each object will be something like

    int id = jsonObject.getInt("id"); //3333
    String title = jsonObject.getString("title"); //My title
}
```

Comment: You should check to make sure the objects contain the requested values before you try to grab them - otherwise an exception will break the entire processing loop.